# alter table by initializing with counts from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables employee and manager on my ORACLE database.

```
employee
id            manager_id
1                005
2                006
3                005
4                008


manager
manager_id
005
006
007
008
```

I want to add a new column to the manager table with the count of employees he is managing.

I did this using two SQL statements

```
ALTER TABLE manager ADD count_emps NUMBER(7);
SELECT count(*) FROM employees GROUP BY manager_id;
```

I'm not sure how to put them together. And I'd like to know any easier alternative ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you add the column, you can do:

```
update manager
    set count_emps = (select count(*)
                      from employees e
                      where e.manager_id = manager.manager_id
                     );
```

Answer (score 2):

`ALTER TABLE` can not be combined with the `DML` from another table.

You need to do it in two steps:

**Step#1:**

```
ALTER TABLE MANAGER ADD COUNT_EMPS NUMBER(7);
```

**Step#2:**

```
MERGE INTO MANAGER M
USING (SELECT E.MANAGER_ID, COUNT(1) AS CNT FROM EMPLOYEE E GROUP BY E.MANAGER_ID) E
ON (M.MANAGER_ID = E.MANAGER_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET M.COUNT_EMPS = E.CNT;
```

I would suggest creating a view for this type of requirement. Otherwise, you will have to update this column's value each time employee's manager is changed.

You can create the desired view as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MANAGER_VIEW AS
SELECT M.MANAGER_ID, M.MANAGER_NAME , COUNT(1) AS COUNT_EMPS
FROM MANAGER M JOIN EMPLOYEE E
ON E.MANAGER_ID =  M.MANAGER_ID
GROUP BY M.MANAGER_ID, M.MANAGER_NAME;
```